# Redirect to another page in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want that when clicking and accepting the warning, I am redirected to another page.
but it doesn't redirect me.

```html
//botón Imprimir
$(document).on("click", ".btnImprimir", function(){    
    fila = $(this);
    id = parseInt($(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').text());
    opcion = 4 //imprimir
    var respuesta = confirm("Imprimir la reserva: "+id+"?");
    if(respuesta){
        $.ajax({
            url: "bd/crud.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {opcion:opcion, id:id},
            success: function(data){
                if(data){
                    window.location.replace("../pdf/pdf.php");
                }
                 
            }
        });
    }  
});
```

Comment: Are you sure is coming in the if?

Comment: Add `error: function ( ) { }` to catch any errors.

Comment: ERROR:'window' is not defined. [no-undef] window.location.href="../pdf/print.php";